# Fantasy TV series from the 80s with a ghost and suit of armour?

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, ghost

I am looking for a children's television series from the 1980s, it has a boy going into a haunted castle in which there was a ghost and a suit of armour that could both talk, they didn't like each other but towards the end of the series they made up to save the boy from some threat.

I was very young at the time so I think it was 1984 to 1986 ish when I would have watched it. Being in infant school I think, because at the same point we used to watch Finger Mouse.

Got a feeling their were only 2 or 3 episodes although it may be it was a film we watched in multiple parts.

Comment: Was this show animated, live action, or puppetry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the points you have listed, I think that the series (it may have been a movie broadcast or shown in separate parts) you are looking for is called *Dark Towers*, part of a BBC childrens educational series called *Look And Read*.

It includes a Helpful Ghost, a Suit Of Armor (Tall Knight, played by none other than Peter Mayhew of Chewbacca fame!) , and a Castle/Mansion/Tower where a treasure is stored and danger abounds.

I've tried to find some solid information on it, so far the only thing I have is [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Towers) and there a few youtube videos for it that I cannot fully link or view due to the limitations on the network I am on at the moment.

Comment: Just FYI, you spelled Wikipedia that way :P I just formatted the URL and didn't notice the spelling.

Comment: Great find! Now it makes sense why I watched it in lower primary school with the guided reading and word explanations.!